# Android: Multiple image view

Tags: java, android

I want two `ImageView's` on one activity view, One image for the profile picture and the other for the profile cover page.

My code

```
setupImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
              bringImagePicker();
            }
});

private void bringImagePicker() {
        // start picker to get image for cropping and then use the image in cropping activity
        CropImage.activity()
                .setGuidelines(CropImageView.Guidelines.ON)
                .setAspectRatio(1,1)
                .start(SetupActivity.this);
    }


@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
            CropImage.ActivityResult result = CropImage.getActivityResult(data);
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                mainImageURI = result.getUri();
                setupImage.setImageURI(mainImageURI);
                isChanged = true;
            } else if (resultCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_RESULT_ERROR_CODE) {
                Exception error = result.getError();
            }
        }
    }
```

Now how can I add for profile cover image?

Comment: profileImg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                  bringImagePickerCoverImg();
                }
    });    but it replace old image not set to profile cover image view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ID for both of them, and change the image with corresponding ID from the intent that holds data, add another condition after receiving the results. 
I don't know if this library can handle this or not.
If not this simplest solution to hold state variable that tells you which image to update
feel free to ask for clarification

Comment: please take note this isn't the best solution but it'll work well
https://ideone.com/YzFMng

Comment: Thanks for your help it help at least. if you need any favor in wordpress/magento let me know